# Disambiguating a variable name in a function when a column with the same name as the variable exists (data.table)

Tags: r, function, dplyr, data.table, nse

I have a function with a variable named `source`. The function works properly, but if the data frame on which the function is applied has a column also named `source`, it doesn't work.

A simple example with dplyr and filtering:
These two following lines works, but they filter based on the column (I want to filter on the variable name defined in the function):

```
corpus %>% dplyr::filter(!!source=="027021335")
corpus %>% dplyr::filter(source=="027021335")
```

This following line work and properly use the variable defined in the function:

```
corpus %>% dplyr::filter(!!rlang::sym(source)=="027021335")
```

How to achieve the same thing using data.table()? I have tried numerous combination of `c()`, `get()` and `..` without managing to make it work. I thought that `corpus[get(source)=="027021335"]` should have worked  but it is not the case as it returns a `first argument has length > 1` error.

Edit:
I think one possible reason I get this error is that in addition to source as a variable and as a column name, there is a source() function is base r.

Corpus using dput(corpus):

```
structure(list(idref = c("027021335", "182132870", "221468579", 
"034574654", "069546592", "159340950", "169800458", "028529413", 
"076605442", "026762889"), iddoc = c(97466L, 101100L, 103772L, 
110039L, 134077L, 55693L, 38787L, 39304L, 73483L, 74350L), nom = c("Méhaut", 
"Favre", "Guerdjikova", "Diebolt", "Giraud-Héraud", "Charlier", 
"Moumni", "Henni", "Bonnel", "Callens"), prenom = c("Philippe", 
"Karine", "Ani", "Claude", "Eric", "Christophe", "Nicolas", "Ahmed", 
"Patrick", "Stéphane"), order = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), role = c("supervisor", "supervisor", "supervisor", "supervisor", 
"supervisor", "supervisor", "supervisor", "supervisor", "supervisor", 
"supervisor"), Annee_soutenance = c("2011", "2014", "2018", "2009", 
"2006", "2015", "2012", "2008", "2009", "2010"), source = c("as.character(idref)", 
"as.character(idref)", "as.character(idref)", "as.character(idref)", 
"as.character(idref)", "as.character(idref)", "as.character(idref)", 
"as.character(idref)", "as.character(idref)", "as.character(idref)"
), time_variable = c("as.character(idref)", "as.character(idref)", 
"as.character(idref)", "as.character(idref)", "as.character(idref)", 
"as.character(idref)", "as.character(idref)", "as.character(idref)", 
"as.character(idref)", "as.character(idref)")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001ee3a911ef0>)
```

Comment: please share your data `corpus` using `dput(corpus)`

Comment: Why don't you just call your function something else? Using a name that is also in your data frame and is a base function just seems like a recipe for unintended consequences...

Comment: I will probably end up doing that, but I figured it might be a good learning opportunity. In the case of network analysis, "source" and "target" are very common variable names that people easily understand. Changing it to "source_column" or "Source" reduce consistency in the case the function get published a part of a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `data.table` development version (1.14.3), this can be done with the new `env` argument, see [programming on data.table](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html):

```
data.table::update.dev.pkg()
source = "idref"
corpus[source=="027021335",env=list(source=source)]

       idref iddoc    nom   prenom order       role Annee_soutenance              source       time_variable
1: 027021335 97466 Méhaut Philippe     0 supervisor             2011 as.character(idref) as.character(idref)
```

Comment: It worked thanks! Any advice on how to chose/prioritize `..` vs `get()` vs `env=list()` when writing a function ? I find these errors hard to anticipate when writing the function and spend a lot of time debugging these issues.

Comment: Thank you for the article. There is one last thing that is unclear to me as I don't understand everything from the article. Within a longer function, do you have to use env=list() for every line calling defined variables ?
Let's say:


`corpus[source=="027021335",env=list(source=source)]`
`corpus[target=="027021335",env=list(target=target)]`
`corpus[target==source,env=list(target=target, source=source)]`


This is the new best practice? There is no way to avoid the burden of the added env argument for each line? I can see the advantages, but the syntax is a bit heavy no? @Waldi

Comment: As soon as `v1.14.3` comes into production, [get](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html#get) will be retired, so I would definitely go for `env`.  `env` is perhaps a bit heavy, but makes substitution explicit.